# How to change component that is rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm super new to React.js. I'm making changeable layouts using React.js. so i tried to use useState for rendering specific layout that I should click. so I tried to add setState for changing false in a function and made one another setState in the same function. but Too many re-renders Error came out. so what can i use for making changeable layout??

this is my code

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Panel from "./Panel";
import PanelTwo from "./PanelTwo";
import styled from "styled-components";
export default function Layout() {
  const [showPanel, setShowPanel] = useState(false);
  const [showPanel1, setShowPanel1] = useState(false);
  const handleOnClick = () => setShowPanel(true);
  const handleOnClick1 = () => setShowPanel1(true);

  return (
    <div>
      <Main>
        <div onClick={handleOnClick}>
          <h1>Panel (1+3)</h1>
        </div>
        <div onClick={handleOnClick1}>
          <h1>Panel (2+2) </h1>
        </div>

        <div>
          <h1>Panel (2+3)</h1>
        </div>

        <div>
          <h1>Panel (2+4)</h1>
        </div>

        <div>
          <h1>Panel (3+1)</h1>
        </div>

        <div>
          <h1>Panel (3+2)</h1>
        </div>
      </Main>
      {showPanel ? <Panel /> : null}
      {showPanel1 ? <PanelTwo /> : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

and if i do this, it looks like this when i click two buttons
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEg49.png)

so i tried this .

```js
 const [showPanel, setShowPanel] = useState(false);
  const [showPanel1, setShowPanel1] = useState(false);
  const handleOnClick = () => setShowPanel(true);
  const handleOnClick1 = () => setShowPanel(false);
  setShowPanel1(true);
```

and i got Too many re-renders Error.

this is what i want to do

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jlQi.png)
when i click each buttons then the exact only one layout is gonna show up .
but the problem is that it's overlapped when i click two buttons
like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEpfo.png)
I'm sorry if my explanation is not good.

Comment: Well the `setShowPanel1(true);` in the function body is what is triggering the render looping, other than this it's unclear what you want the UI to do. Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and provide more details about expected versus actual behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you really just want to toggle between the two layouts. You can do this with a single state value, callback, and conditional render via ternary.

```
export default function Layout() {
  const [showPanel, setShowPanel] = useState(false);

  const handleOnClick = () => setShowPanel(show => !show);

  return (
    <div>
      <Main>
        <div onClick={handleOnClick}>
          <h1>Panel (1+3)</h1>
        </div>
        <div onClick={handleOnClick}>
          <h1>Panel (2+2) </h1>
        </div>

        ...
      </Main>
      {showPanel ? <Panel /> : <PanelTwo />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

OFC, this assumes you want to always show ***at least one*** of the layouts. If you want to start with both initially hidden (i.e. `false`) then you can toggle the other panel state false in the handlers to do that.

```
export default function Layout() {
  const [showPanel, setShowPanel] = useState(false);
  const [showPanel1, setShowPanel1] = useState(false);

  const handleOnClick = () => {
    setShowPanel(true);
    setShowPanel1(false);
  };

  const handleOnClick1 = () => {
    setShowPanel(false);
    setShowPanel1(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Main>
        <div onClick={handleOnClick}>
          <h1>Panel (1+3)</h1>
        </div>
        <div onClick={handleOnClick1}>
          <h1>Panel (2+2) </h1>
        </div>

        ...
      </Main>
      {showPanel && <Panel />}
      {showPanel1 && <PanelTwo />}
    </div>
  );
}
```